# Python Selenium : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to HTML and Selenium, and I have struggling with the following error:

*raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(),'Manage Users')]"}*

I have tried a wide array of various combinations of attributes, and to no avail. I can't directly use the ID of the element because it is dynamic. The code below is a fraction of the combinations that I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url')

driver.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys('my_username')
driver.find_element_by_id('j_password').send_keys('my_password')
driver.find_element_by_id('button.ok').click()

time.sleep(3)

driver.switch_to.frame('portfolio_canvas_area')
driver.switch_to.frame('portfolio_area')

time.sleep(5)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/form/span/span[1]/span/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/span/a")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Manage Users')]")
#WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/form/span/span[1]/span/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/span/a'))).click()
#WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//span[text()="Manage Users"]'))).click()
```

The following is the HTML in question giving me issues:

```
<a href="javascript:action('https://website.com/itim/console/action/Te502a9571b590da5d71c7#W5f82fbdc1b590c3ea782a_treeSel(3)')" id="W5f82fbdc1b590c3ea782a_treeSel(3)" name="W5f82fbdc1b590c3ea782a_treeSel(3)" onclick="if (confirmPageChange()) {saveTaskFormElements();return doSubmit('form', 'W5f82fbdc1b590c3ea782a_treeSel', 'treeSel(3)', 'W5f82fbdc1b590c3ea782a_treeSel(3)', 'treeFunc', 'wh', 'wa'); }" style="color:#000000;font-size:83.3%;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" taskid="MANAGE_USERS" title="Manage Users">Manage Users</a>
```

I have also attached some pictures of parent HTML code from Chrome's Inspector with this question. I would greatly appreciate your help in relieving some of the headaches that this has caused! Thank you!

[image]
[image]
The following picture shows the webpage, where buttons on the left frame opens up a new tab displayed on the right frame.
[image]

Comment: There might be a 3rd frame taskentriesframe.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan That's exactly it! Thanks so much, I totally missed it!

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that selenium could not locate the element.

So maybe you can try using the following example, I use it all the time to avoid errors like this.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Manage Users']").click()
```

if that doesn't work, here is a list of things you can try

```
# 1
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

# 2
# make sure the text "Manage Users" don't have space before or after in the HTML code

# 3
# It seems that the "Manage Users" button is a link so you can try the link method
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Manage Users").click()  

# 4
# You can also try with ActionChains, need to import the module first
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains  

# then you have try the following
actions = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Manage Users']")
actions.move_to_element(element).click(on_element=element).perform()
```

Hopes this helped!